# Map only first n items in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have a react function that maps my array and renders components;

```
const urls = [
'http://localhost:3005/products/774944', 
'http://localhost:3005/products/774945', 
'http://localhost:3005/products/774946',
'http://localhost:3005/products/123581', 
'http://localhost:3005/products/782691', 
'http://localhost:3005/products/782485',
'http://localhost:3005/products/782486', 
'http://localhost:3005/products/782487', 
'http://localhost:3005/products/782488',
'http://localhost:3005/products/738471'];

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('root'));

let show_items = () => {
ReactDOM.render(urls.map((url)=>{
    return(
      <Item url={url}/>
    )
    }), document.getElementById('items'));
}

show_items()
```

I would like to map only the first few items from 'urls' array. The only thing that comes to my mind is to slice array, but I am curious to know if there is a better way

Comment: Slicing is idiomatic and perfectly appropriate here. 

Comment: Slice is a best option